# i need to parse json file in 10 files interval

Tags: javascript, json

i am getting json data from a files and create another json files in each loop and send request for that json files here is my code for creating json files

```
var  derivatedFeatures = ["RMS","sb2xMagnitudev_ipspeak", "sbSubsynchronousv_ipspeak", "PeakPeak_mil", "sbHighFrequency_grms", "TruePeak_ips", "PeakPeak_g", "sb1xMagnitudev_ipspeak","Crestfactor"];

$.each(derivatedFeatures,function(index,feature){

  $.each(data,function(index,item){

    var featurefile ="Lines_"+feature+'_'+item['Line']+'_'+item['Component'].split(" ").join("_")+'.json'

    filedata = {
      file:featurefile,
      site:item['Site'],
      area:item['Area'],
      line:item['Line'],
      equipment:item['Equipment'],
      component:item['Component'],
      feature:feature
    };

    frank.sendAjax('/static/data/json/'+featurefile,'', 'GET', anomaliesDataAppend,filedata);
  });
});
```

- i want to load 10 files first
- after page scroll i want to load 10 more
- and processes continue

  **Reason for doing this**
- page stuck while loading all of json files and processing its data
- i have 2000+ json files

Comment: The people here are trying to help. It would be good if you can help them by indented code properly. Instead of letting others try to clean up your code.

Comment: 2000 request is worth, than one big. You can join 2000 json files all together. How do they create and store?

Comment: Usually `setTimeout(function(){}, 0)` prevents from UI hanging.

Comment: @Pinal the files are itself very big . One single file have lots of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i hope this help you:
here is i coded for your solution

```
$.each(derivatedFeatures,function(index,feature){

                            $.each(data,function(index,item){
                                indexnum++;
                         var featurefile ="Lines_"+feature+'_'+item['Line']+'_'+item['Component'].split(" ").join("_")+'.json'
                         filedata.push({file:featurefile,
                            site:item['Site'],
                            area:item['Area'],
                            line:item['Line'],
                            equipment:item['Equipment'],
                            component:item['Component'],
                            feature:feature,
                            indexnum:indexnum
                        });
                            });


                    });
                    loadFeatureFiles(filedata,0);




   var loadFeatureFiles = function(filedata,indexnum){
    var startfrom=indexnum;
    var endto=startfrom+10;
    for (var i=startfrom;i <= endto;i++) {
        requestdata={filedata:filedata[i],indexnum:i};
          frank.sendAjax('/static/data/json/'+filedata[i]['file'],'', 'GET', anomaliesDataAppend,requestdata);
    };
};
```

assign data= rows and get when user scroll down and pass in the function

```
//data is induxnum
      loadFeatureFiles(filedata,data);
```